# Does Academic Research Destroy Stock Return Predictability?

Tags: equities, portfolio-management, finance, statistics, research

[McLean/Pontiff (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1111/jofi.12365) give evidence that portfolio returns are 26% lower out-of-sample and 58% lower after publishing an academic paper on variables, which are likely to predict cross-sectional returns:

> Our findings suggest that investors learn about mispricing from academic publications. [...] This result is also consistent with the idea that academic research draws trading attention to the predictors.

**Isn't this a self-fulfilling prophecy, having regard to the [data-snooping bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging)?**

Assume [data-snooping](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2962077) leads us to a variable which explains the cross-section of stock returns and luckily passes some robustness tests. After publishing our paper, the market adopts our findings and diminishes strategies based on our variable - although there is no economic reason to do so! In fact, anyone thinks of a previous mispricing but only after our publication *real mispricing* arises.

Comment: Only anecdotal evidence. Dong Lou once said that one of the big investment banks tried for him not to circulate this paper: http://personal.lse.ac.uk/loud/ATugofWar.pdf
precisely because it was the type of trading they were doing.